# package calc Error :\gdef invalid at this point \title

Tags: errors, titles

I get the following error message when I try to compile the code below.

```
package calc Error :'\gdef' invalid at this point \title
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% permet de faire une table des matieres par chapitre
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\setlength{\parindent}
% biblio ordonnee classique 
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\title {Titre}
\author{Sssss}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
% le titre

\maketitle

% preparation des minitocs
\dominitoc

% table des matieres generale
\tableofcontents
\include{intro}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}
\include{conclu}

\appendix

\include{annexe}

% bibliographie
\bibliography{allbiblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're missing a mandatory argument to `\setlength`: it should be `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` if you ***really*** want a zero parindent. Please, don't (and don't use a nonzero parskip either).

Comment: `\setlength` requires two arguments (the length in question and the value to be assigned) but you're only supplying the first argument. In your code, `\title` is taken as the second argument to `\setlength`. Then, the world ends.

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax for `\setlength` requires a second argument; you probably want

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

---

Please, avoid setting `\parskip` to such a high value as 10pt. Your pages will be crossed by big white stripes that don't make reading easier in any way. However I can't recommend smaller values either. Paragraph indentation has served well typography and readers for five centuries; it's discreet an unobtrusive, while the nonzero parskip is saying “Look at me”.